# Trying to change table lines, width, height and font size and color

Tags: tables, fontsize, tabularx, sharelatex

I need some help with formatting this table. Can't manage to figure out how to change width and height without messing up the whole table, as well as the font size and color.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ p{14mm} | p{14mm} | p{14mm} | p{14mm} | p{14mm} | p{14mm} | p{14mm} }
Plan & Special* & Platinum & Gold & Silver & Bronze & Red\\ 
\hline
Website \& Banners & X & X & X & X & X & X \\
\hline
Car & X & X & X & X \\
\hline
Size (cm^2) & Custom & 2.5 x 90 - 5 x 60 & 2.5 x 25 - 5 x 40 & 5 x 15 &  \\  
\hline
T-Shirts & X & X & X & X & X\\
\end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried using slashbox which is nicer but still would be right on the document

```
\begin{tabular}{l||*{6}{c}}
\backslashbox{Logo}{Plans}
&\makebox[3em]{Special}&\makebox[3em]{Platinum}&\makebox[3em]{Gold}
&\makebox[3em]{Silver}&\makebox[3em]{Bronze}&\makebox[3em]{Red}\\\hline\hline
Website \\ \& \\ Banners &X&X&X&X&X&X\\\hline
T-Shirts &x&X&X&X&X&\\\hline
Car &X&X&X&X&&\\\hline
Size &Custom&$2.5 \times 90 - 5 \times 60$ &$2.5 \times 25 - 5 \times 40$&$5 \times 
15$&&\\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

```
\begin{center}
\mbox{
\scalebox{1.18}{
   \begin{center}
   \tiny{
   \textcolor{textcol}{
\begin{tabularx}{.8632\textwidth}{@{} l |  *{6}{C|} @{}}
\toprule
\backslashbox{Logo}{Plan}
 & Special* & Platinum & Gold & Silver & Bronze & Red\\ \hline
\midrule
Website \& Banners  & X & X & X & X     & X & X \\\hline
\addlinespace
T-Shirts            & X & X & X & X     &   &   \\\hline
Car                 & X & X & X & X     &   &   \\\hline
Size (cm$^2$)
& Custom
    & $2.5{\times}90 - 5{\times}60$
        & $2.5{\times}25 - 5{\times}40$
            & $5{\times}15$         &   &   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
}}
\end{center} 
}
}
\end{center}
```

[image: Trying to get the proportional size. Now, it's too small and when I change from tiny to small it gets too big and scaling doesnt help]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code snippet co complete small document beginning with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document`. btw, at column specifier `c` you cant define width of column.

Comment: What would like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\noindent\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X *6{|l} }
Plan & Special* & Platinum & Gold & Silver & Bronze & Red\\ \hline
Website \& Banners & X & X & X & X & X & X \\\hline
Car & X & X & X & X & X\\\hline
Size (cm${}^2$) & Custom & $2.5 \times 90 - 5 \times 60$ & $2.5 \times 25 - 5 \times 40$ & $5 \times 15$ &  \\\hline
T-Shirts & X & X & X & X & X\\
\end{tabularx}

\normalsize
foo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Herbert! but it's still not working check my next answer

Answer (score 1):

two examples with using `tabularx` table environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setcellgapes{5pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} | l | *{6}{C|} @{}}
    \hline
Plan & Special* & Platinum & Gold & Silver & Bronze & Red\\
    \hline
Website \& Banners  & X & X & X & X     & X & X \\
    \hline
Car                 & X & X & X & X     &   &   \\
    \hline
Size (cm$^2$)
    & Custom
        & $2.5{\times}90 - 5{\times}60$
            & $2.5{\times}25 - 5{\times}40$
                & $5{\times}15$         &   &   \\
    \hline
T-Shirts            & X & X & X & X     &   &   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l  *{6}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
Plan & Special* & Platinum & Gold & Silver & Bronze & Red\\
    \midrule
Website \& Banners  & X & X & X & X     & X & X \\
Car                 & X & X & X & X     &   &   \\
    \addlinespace
Size (cm$^2$)
    & Custom
        & $2.5{\times}90 - 5{\times}60$
            & $2.5{\times}25 - 5{\times}40$
                & $5{\times}15$         &   &   \\
T-Shirts            & X & X & X & X     &   &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)